# C++ Iterating through map from pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stdmap

I want to iterate through a map, which address is stored in a pointer, so I can access and modify the original map, however whenever I try to iterate, it always gives me a read access violation.

```
#include <map>

template<typename A, typename B>
class map_array_util
{
public:
map_array_util(std::map<A,B> _m)
{
    m = &_m;
}

void copy(B *arr, int size)
{

}

bool equals(B *arr, int size) const
{
    int i = 0;
    for (auto it = (*m).begin(); it != (*m).end(); ++it)
    {
        std::pair<A, B> p = *it;
        if (*(arr + i) != p.second)
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return true;
}
private:
std::map<A, B> *m;
};
```

How do we iterate in the correct way?

Comment: `map_array_util(std::map<A,B>& _m)` instead of `map_array_util(std::map<A,B> _m)` and then you have to make sure, your map doesn't get removed from the stack or where ever you've stored the map after invokation of `map_array_util`. Btw. this isn't good practice.

Comment: `(*ptr).mbr` is what the `->` operator is meant for : `ptr->mbr`.

Comment: BTW: `bool equals(B *arr, int size) const {return std::equal(arr, arr + size(), m->begin(), m->end(), [](const B& b, const auto& p){ return b == p.second; });}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You store address of local copy with

```
map_array_util(std::map<A,B> _m)
{
    m = &_m;
}
```

So you have dangling pointer.

You probably want to pass by reference:

```
map_array_util(std::map<A,B>& _m) : m(&_m) {}
```

Comment: Thats it. Thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `map_array_util(std::map<A,B> _m)`, you possibly meant

```
map_array_util(std::map<A,B> &_m)
//                           ^
```

BTW this class is not a good idea IMO. You can better drive your class from a reference_wrapper.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment about reference_wrapper?

Comment: I meant https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper